# Intrusion Detection System OSSEC

Tags: configuration, ossec

I configured the OSSEC by following the procedure from https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/06/30/how-to-install-and-configure-ossec-on-ubuntu-linux/ this site. but after configuration, when I tried /var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart 
I got

ossec-monitord not running ..
ossec-logcollector not running ..
ossec-remoted not running ..
ossec-syscheckd not running ..
ossec-analysisd not running ..
ossec-maild not running ..
ossec-execd not running ..
OSSEC HIDS v2.9.0 Stopped
Starting OSSEC HIDS v2.9.0 (by Trend Micro Inc.)...
OSSEC analysisd: Testing rules failed. Configuration error. Exiting.

In logtest, I got

Error reading XML file '/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf': XMLERR: Element 'syscheck' not closed. (line 252).
2018/05/22 15:20:59 ossec-testrule(1202): ERROR: Configuration error at '/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf'. Exiting.

where can I solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You have to close the  tag in your config file,
Edit ossec.conf :

Type *<\syscheck>* where you opend it.